# Download and Open Compressed SQLite3 Database on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, heroku

I have a script file for parsing through a SQLite database. I now need to create a CRON job that will download and unzip said database from a third-party (already hosting as SQLITE). I understand this can be done using WGET and UNZIP, but given Heroku's read only file system, is this possible entirely in memory? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku's file system is read-only but you can use the `tmp` and `log` directory from within your application folder.

From [Heroku's doc](http://docs.heroku.com/constraints#read-only-filesystem):

*There are two directories that are writeable: ./tmp and ./log (under your application root). If you wish to drop a file temporarily for the duration of the request, you can write to a filename like #{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/myfile_#{Process.pid}. There is no guarantee that this file will be there on subsequent requests (although it might be), so this should not be used for any kind of permanent storage.*